# Why am I getting extra output for linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

The question is

There is a collection of input strings and a collection of query strings. For each query string, determine how many times it occurs in the list of input strings.

strings = [ab,ab,abc]
queries = [ab,abc,bc]
There are  instances 2 of ab, 1 of 'abc' and 0 of 'bc'. For each query, add an element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
}*first=NULL,*last= new node;
void create(int count) {
    node *temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->data = count;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(!first) first=last=temp;
    else {
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}
void display() {
    node *temp = first;
    while(temp) {
        cout<<temp->data<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void matchStrings(string s[],string q[],int s_count,int q_count){
    int counter;
    // res = new int[q_count];
        for(int i=0;i<=q_count;i++){
            counter = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<s_count;j++){
                if( q[i] == s[j] ) counter++;
            }
            if(counter != 0) create(counter);
            else create(0);
        }
    // return res;
}
int main() {
     int string_count,query_count,*res;

     cin>>string_count;
     string strings[string_count];
     for(int i=0;i<string_count;i++) cin>>strings[i];

    cin>>query_count;
    string queries[query_count];
    for(int i=0;i<query_count;i++) cin>>queries[i];
    matchStrings(strings,queries,string_count,query_count);

    // res = matchStrings(strings,queries,string_count,query_count);
    matchStrings(strings,queries,string_count,query_count);
    

    // for(int i=0;i<query_count;i++) cout<<res[i]<<endl;

    display();


    return 0;
}
```

Now I am trying to implement it using Linked List but instead of getting output as 2,1,0.
I am getting output as 2,1,0,2,2,1,0,2.
I dont how is the LL being created for more than 3 links.
Please help.

Comment: This: `for (int i = 0; i <= q_count; i++)` looks suspicious. The `<=` should be just `<`. I think there's your extra query.

Comment: (And `if (counter != 0) create(counter); else create(0);` can be written as `create(counter);`)

Comment: Since you know which test case we should look at, there is no need for your [mre] to ask for user input. Hardcode values for the Stack Overflow version of your code.

Comment: I guess that was by mistake but  now I am still getting output as 2,1,0,2,1,0 .Still there is an extra execution and that create(0) is to get the 0 as output.

Comment: `*last= new node;` -- generally `last` (or `tail`) is simply a pointer to the last node in the list to allow ordered insertion in O(1) time, it doesn't have allocated storage of its own.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `void matchStrings()`,
you have written

`for(int i=0;`*`i<=q_count;`*`i++){`

Rather it should be

`for(int i=0;`**`i<q_count;`**`i++){`

Because of the extra iteration, a randomly generated string gets checked with the set of `strings[]`, and as a result they are incorrectly matched.

So this leads to the execution of `create(0)` one extra time, which results in creating an extra node with data 0, that gets printed.

Comment: But now I am getting output as 2,1,0,2,1,0.There is still an extra execution.

Comment: @RoshanAhmadShaheen, but you make the same call twice in `main`... what did you expect?

Comment: @RoshanAhmadShaheen this is because you are calling `matchstrings()` function twice in the main method. So it creates total 6 nodes in the linked list, first 3 for the first call and the other 3 for the 2nd call